# Adding class when screen is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have no knowledge of js, but I am trying to add a class to a div when any point of the screen is clicked. I have this html

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

And I need to add the class to the container when any point of the screen is clicked.

I tried this js

```
<script>
let button = document.querySelector('.container');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
button.classList.add('.hide');
});
</script>
```

but it is not working, the class is not being applied. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the dot from the class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small syntax error: the class should be mentioned without the dot prefix:

```
button.classList.add('hide');
```

#### Demo

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.container');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    button.classList.add('hide');
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
  background-color: #ccf;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<br>  
   <div class="box">Click anywhere in the grey container to hide it</div>
   <br>  
</div>
```

Comment: it is still not working - the class is not added.

Comment: It should work, c.f. edited answer with a demo. If there is still a problem, then please edit the question to add a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Okay, this is working, however, my planned use for it is not working since there seems to be a conflict in the js that is already on the page. The class "container" is only loaded when a button is clicked(via js), so for some reason the class"hide" is not added to it.

Comment: I see. Have a look at [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to solve that one...